# approximation $\arctan \alpha$ with $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis

Can I approximate $\arctan \alpha$ with $\alpha$  for an $\alpha$ near to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5-...$$

Answer (score 1):

Even without the Taylor development you can do it since
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\arctan x}}
{x} = 1
$$
and this means that 
$$
\arctan x = x + o(x)\,\,\,\,\,\left( {x \to 0} \right)
$$